# Pandas str alphabetically then numerically

Tags: python, string, pandas, sorting, dataframe

This is probably a simple question and I just couldn't find the answer. In a pandas DataFrame like the one below, how can the objects be sorted first alphabetically and then numerically.

**START:**

```
import pandas as pd

d ={'col1': ['A1','B2','A10','A7','C4','C2','C22','B4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

  col1
0   A1
1   A7
2  A10
3   B2
4   B4
5   C2
6   C4
7  C22
```

**WHAT I WANT TO GET:**

```
  col1
0   A1
1   A7
2  A10
3   B2
4   B4
5   C2
6   C4
7  C22
```

**WHAT I GET:**

```
>>>df.sort_values(by='col1')

  col1
0   A1
2  A10
1   A7
3   B2
4   B4
5   C2
7  C22
6   C4
```

Comment: what is type of lot_file['SPOOL']?

Comment: That is not a valid list, unless A39 etc are variable names.  At least provide something we can reproduce

Comment: Also, what is your sorting logic? Does "A30" come before "A4" ?

Answer (score 1):

This is overkill to use Pandas to sort a list:

```
lot_file = pd.DataFrame()
lot_file['SPOOL'] = ['A39','B34','A3','B37','A6','B18','A48','B15','A47']
group_lots = lot_file.sort_values(by=['SPOOL'])
group_lots['SPOOL'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['A3', 'A39', 'A47', 'A48', 'A6', 'B15', 'B18', 'B34', 'B37']
```

Or use `sorted`

```
spool_list = ['A39','B34','A3','B37','A6','B18','A48','B15','A47']
sorted(spool_list)
```

Output:

```
['A3', 'A39', 'A47', 'A48', 'A6', 'B15', 'B18', 'B34', 'B37']
```

Comment: Agreed - and for the correct order one could use the key `sorted(spool_list, key=lambda x: 10**2*ord(x[0]) + int(x[1:]))`